# Transit visa through Germany

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, airport-transfer

I have an Indian passport and a valid US visa. I have two stopovers in Frankfurt and Munich while going to India with Lufthansa. I have a change of flight in both places. Do I need an airport transit visa?

Answer (score -2):

You don't need an ATV [as you are coming from the U.S.](http://www.germany.info/contentblob/4874040/Daten/7545420/Airport_Transit_Country_List.pdf), **but you may need a regular Schengen Visa.**

The latter  depends on whether you are staying in the international part of Frankfurt and Munich Airports or if you have to enter Germany, e.g. for a domestic flight between Frankfurt and Munich. Your airline can answer you that for the specific flight you have booked

Comment: Absolutely needs a Schengen visa! Frankfurt -> Munich is a domestic flight in every sense of the word.